# Is it possible to set automatic refresh of MQT in DB2?

Tags: database, db2, administration, materialized-views

Is there any other way to schedule the refresh? Say I want to refresh the MQT every 2 hours. Is that possible?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_MQT (average, sum, max) as (
    SELECT
        avg(table1.field1) as average,
        sum(table2.field2) as sum,
        max(table3.field3) as max 
    FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
)
DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED
REFRESH DEFERRED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DB2 9.7, you could write a stored procedure to handle the refresh and use the [Administrative Task Scheduler](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0054399.html) to execute it.  Or, use cron to schedule it, if you want to use something not inside the database.

If you are needing to refresh your MQT so frequently, have you considered using a refresh immediate MQT, to avoid this maintenance entirely?

Comment: Db2 not allow to create my MQT with refresh immediate  option,